# React Native - Calling a function

Tags: react-native

I am new to `react-native` but have been playing around with creating a simple login UI. I have a Login component and then two seperate form components for `loginForm` and `forgotPasswordForm`.

On my Login Component, I have a `renderForm` function that is trying to determine if we should show the `loginForm` or the `forgotPasswordForm`, which I assume would be based on `state`.

**Login Component:**

```
export default class Login extends Component {
  state = { 'display': '' };

  // Render the content
  renderForm(){
    // What page should show?
    switch(this.state.display){
      case 'forgotPasswordForm':
        return <ForgotPassword />;
      break;
      case 'loginForm':
        return <LoginForm />;
      break;
      default:
        return <LoginForm />;
      break;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>

        <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
          <Image
            style={styles.logo}
            source={require('../../images/logo.png')}
          />
          <Text style={styles.logoText}>Behavior Tracking System</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          {this.renderForm()}
        </View>

      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my `LoginForm` which contains a link to the `forgotPasswordFunction`:

```
export default class LoginForm extends Component {

  forgotPasswordForm(){
    // Thought I could setState here so that the loginComponent would update and see the state and render the forgotPasswordForm instead
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar
          barStyle="light-content"
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="username or email"
          placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
          returnKeyType="next"
          onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
          keyboardType="email-address"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="password"
          placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
          secureTextEntry={true}
          returnKeyType="go"
          style={styles.input}
          ref={(input) => this.passwordInput = input}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.forgotPasswordContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.forgotPasswordText}>Trouble logging in? </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.forgotPasswordForm()}>
            <Text style={styles.activeLink}>Click Here.</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

I may be just a little confused at where some of this code should be placed. I assume since the LoginComponent is including the form fields itself, thats where I would put the switch logic to determine if we show the `loginForm` or `forgotPasswordForm`.

My issue is the `onClick` in the `loginForm` for the forgotPassword link. Not entirely sure how to get that to update the login component to switch forms.

[image]

My goal is that when the "Click Here" link is pressed, it loads the Password Recovery Field instead of the login fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you need to create a function that will update the state in the parent component and pass it down to the child. Now if you call `this.props.forgotPasswordForm()` inside your LoginForm component, it will update the state in the parent and render the ForgotPassword component instead.

```js
export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      display: 'loginForm' 
    }; //this is how  you set up state
  }

  // Render the content
  renderForm = () => {
    // What page should show?
    switch(this.state.display){
      case 'forgotPasswordForm':
        return <ForgotPassword />;
      break;
      case 'loginForm':
        return <LoginForm forgotPasswordForm={this.forgotPasswordForm} />; //pass method to child
      break;
      default:
        return <LoginForm forgotPasswordForm={this.forgotPasswordForm} />;
      break;
    }
  }
  // Create a function that will update the state in parent
  forgotPasswordForm = () => {
    this.setState({ display: 'forgotPasswordForm' });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>

        <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
          <Image
            style={styles.logo}
            source={require('../../images/logo.png')}
          />
          <Text style={styles.logoText}>Behavior Tracking System</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          {this.renderForm()}
        </View>

      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - after making those changes, I receive the following error: "Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor)". The page also defaults to the forgot password form instead of login. Maybe I missed something else?

Comment: I edited the display to 'loginForm' in this.state, also did you make all the changes I did? I also changed the way you were creating the functions from renderForm() {} to renderForm = () => {}

Comment: Oh that error is because you called this.forgotPasswordForm() in your onPress, it should just be `onPress={this.props.forgotPasswordForm}`